# How to measure time improvement of Oracle Configurator module vs generic UI?

Tags: oracle, plsql

My company has been converting models to use the Oracle R12 Configurator module rather than the default, BOM-based UI, and I need to measure the time saved by this effort. I've been working on a query to help me answer this, and I'm running into a wall. I'm an analyst, not a DBA, and have read-only access to tables.

My first question is, which timestamps make for the best measurement of time elapsed? I'm trying, as closely as possible, to capture the moment from the time the user clicks "Configure" on their order, to the moment the configuration populates the order lines.

My second question is, which table & field best distinguish models configured through the generic UI vs the advanced UIs available via the Configurator module?

```
-- Query to pull dates for orders for active OAC models
-- ~135 minutes runtime
-- Really only need item id(# or description), time, and Configurator-type flag,
-- plus order number to check outliers.
SELECT oh.order_number                as "oh.order_number",
   oh.creation_date               as "oh.creation_date",
   cz.config_rev_nbr              as "cz.config_rev_nbr",
   cz.ui_def_id                   as "cz.ui_def_id", 
-- using above to separate default BOM UI from "Advanced" Configurator
-- NULL is default, non-NULL is custom - I think.
   ol.ordered_item                as "ol.ordered_item",
   pubs.description               as "item_description",
   (cz.creation_date-ol.creation_date)*1440 as "configuration_time", 
-- in minutes. 
-- trying to measure time spent from clicking "Configure", to returning to order lines. 
-- I don't think this works anymore with left-join on cz table.
   mp.creation_date                    as "first_published",
   mp.last_update_date                 as "last_OAC_update"
FROM cz.cz_config_hdrs cz,
   ont.oe_order_lines_all ol,
   ont.oe_order_headers_all oh,
   cz.cz_model_publications mp,
   (SELECT si.segment1 item_name,
           si.description,
           mp.publication_id,
           mp.remote_publication_id,
           mp.model_id,
           mp.top_item_id,
           mp.organization_id,
           mp.last_update_date,
           mp.product_key
      FROM cz.cz_model_publications mp, inv.mtl_system_items_b si
     WHERE 1 = 1
       AND mp.top_item_id = si.inventory_item_id
       AND si.organization_id = mp.organization_id
       AND deleted_flag = 0
       AND disabled_flag = 0
       AND sysdate BETWEEN applicable_from AND applicable_until
       AND export_status = 'OK'
       AND object_type = 'PRJ'
       AND source_target_flag = 'T' --only target publications
       AND publication_mode = 'p') pubs 
-- above subquery shows which models currently have an active publication. 
-- adapted from http://www.softraction.com/2013_06_01_archive.html
WHERE ol.config_header_id = cz.config_hdr_id(+) 
-- had to left join to pull in more orders before publication
  AND oh.order_source_id = 22 -- need this to exclude sources other than regular users
  AND oh.flow_status_code in ('BOOKED', 'CLOSED')
/*   AND ol.config_rev_nbr = cz.config_rev_nbr(+)*/ -- can't have multiple left joins on cz
  AND ol.header_id = oh.header_id
  AND ol.ordered_item = pubs.item_name
/*   AND cz.component_id(+) = pubs.model_id*/  -- can't have multiple left joins on cz
  AND cz.ui_def_id = mp.ui_def_id(+);
```

Comment: I think you are doing it right.. Configurator UI will be opened if your model have an active publication. BOM UI will be launched otherwise.